# Remote Backup Solution

Tags: backup, vpn

I have a customer who is looking for an extra backup. He already uses Western Digital's cloud backup as well as swapping out his physical backup drives once a week and bringing it offsite.

He is looking for an offsite backup that is automated and uses his internet connection. I am thinking about going with hamachi or a PPTP VPN and Deltacopy (which will send only the changed files).

Is there a better solution?

Does all hamachi data pass through their servers? The reason that I ask is that I will have to encrypt the transmission with openssh if that's the case.

Comment: You should encrypt it in any case, if it's trekking across the internet.

Comment: That's why I am thinking of going the vpn route. Only one problem, it's a windows 2008 server, but I could skip PPTP altogether and use OpenVPN. Even though OpenVPN is no longer supported on Windows, it should still work.

Answer (score 1):

A tool like GoodSync has options to copy the changed data only safe over LANs or WANs and it has the option to encrypt the data before sending, it uses AES 128 and AES 256 Encryption.